# Advanced customization of InputBox edit control

Tags: vba

So I have some basic VBA code:

```
Sub Test()
    ' Set error handler
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim strElevation As String
    strElevation = InputBox("Enter elevation difference:", "Create Cross Lines", 0.5)

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Call ReportError("Test")
End Sub
```

And it looks fine:

[image: InputBox]

Is it possible to extend this so that the edit box will only allow a numeric value to 2 decimal places? Or is it simply too much work?

I know how to format text itself, eg: `Format("1234.5678", "#.00")`. But can the actual edit control have any customization itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have three options here... In order of difficulty:

**1. Validate the input**

This uses the native `InputBox()` function as you have in your code sample above. You can return the value into a string variable, then do your validation at that point to make sure the data is formatted the way you want. If it doesn't pass, then display the input box again.

**2. Custom VBA form**

If you create your own VBA User Form, you can customize the text box to use a specific format, and perform the validation before the form accepts the input and closes. This is probably the most user-friendly approach, but involves a little more code than the first method.

*Example:*

Create sample VBA form with two input boxes and a command button. Name them `txtDiff1`, `txtDiff2`, and `cmdOK` respectively.

[image]

Double-click one of the controls, and add the following code to the code module behind the form:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    MyElevationDifference = txtDiff1 ' (or txtDiff2)
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub txtDiff1_AfterUpdate()

    Dim dblValue As Double

    If IsNumeric(txtDiff1) Then
        ' Determine rounded amount
        dblValue = Round(txtDiff1, 2)
        ' Automatically round the value
        If dblValue <> CDbl(txtDiff1) Then txtDiff1 = dblValue
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a numeric value", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub txtDiff2_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Dim dblValue As Double

    If IsNumeric(txtDiff2) Then
        ' Determine rounded amount
        dblValue = Round(txtDiff2, 2)
        ' Require a max of 2 decimal places
        If dblValue <> CDbl(txtDiff2) Then
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "Please only use 2 decimal places", vbExclamation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a numeric value", vbExclamation
        ' Cancel change
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Paste the following into a regular code module. (This is how you can get the input in your main code through the custom form. Essentially the form assigns a value to the global variable, and you reference that after showing the form.)

```
Option Explicit

Public MyElevationDifference As Double

Public Sub GetElevationDifference()
    UserForm1.Show
    MsgBox "Elevation difference: " & MyElevationDifference, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Now when you run `GetElevationDifference()`, you will see a couple different approaches demonstrated on the user form. The **first text box** automatically ***rounds* the input**, while the **second text box** does **not allow the user to continue** unless they correct the input to use two decimal places or less.

[image]

Of course you will want to add some error handling and make the form look nice, but this gives you a simple example of how to use a VBA form to get user input. They involve a little more code, but obviously provide a huge level of additional flexibility over the simple `InputBox()` function.

**3. Windows API calls**

Just for completeness, there are ways to use Windows API calls to actually affect the controls on an input box, but this would end up being far more complex than the first two approaches, and I would not recommend it for something like this.

Comment: I agree with your suggestions. Options 1 or 2. Is it possible to flesh out option 2 with the basic methodology? Having said that, there is another answer provided where someone has used `AfterUpdate` event handler.

Comment: Sure, I will add an example to option two... Give me a couple minutes.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can restrict to input box to allow only numeric values:

```
strElevation = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter elevation difference:", Title:="Create Cross Lines", Default:=0.5, Type:=1)
```

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel

To validate the lenght, you can use the following code:

```
Do
  strElevation = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter elevation difference:", Title:="Create Cross Lines", Default:=0.5, Type:=1)

  If Len(strElevation) > 2 Then MsgBox "You typed in too many characters... 2 maximum!"
Loop While Len(strElevation) > 2
```

Comment: 2 decimal places isn't the same as having length of two

Comment: Thanks. Also the application I am using does not support this additional `Type` property.

Comment: Did you already copied the line as I wrote? I had the same problem with the `Type` property but I make it work for my Excel version.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    If InStr(1, Me.TextBox1.Value, ".") > 0 Then
        If Len(Mid(Me.TextBox1.Value, _
            InStr(1, Me.TextBox1.Value, "."), _
            Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) - InStr(1, Me.TextBox1.Value, "."))) > 2 Then
            Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
            MsgBox "cannot have more than 2 decimal places"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Apply to your situation but this gets you there

```
Sub Test()
    ' Set error handler
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim strElevation As String
    strElevation = InputBox("Enter elevation difference:", "Create Cross Lines", 0.5)

    If InStr(1, strElevation, ".") > 0 Then
        If Len(Mid(strElevation, InStr(1, strElevation, "."), Len(strElevation) - InStr(1, strElevation, "."))) > 2 Then
            MsgBox "cannot have more than 2 decimal places"
        End If
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Call ReportError("Test")
End Subc
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is in context of a `TextBox` control on a form and not a `InputBox`.

Comment: @AndrewTuckle the same idea still applies. This is only showing you the methodology. Like string manipulation can be done by simply switching out "Me.Textbox1" for strElevation. see revised answer

Comment: Oh, I see. So your answer basically goes with option 1 in AdamsTips answer.